# How to export statistics_log data to excel after Parameters Variation AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

After running Parameters Variation, how can I export the statistics_log data (or dataset if better practice) to excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an Excel File element in your Parameter Variation experiment window and add a variable of type `int` with initial value of 0.

[image]

Then let's say you want to export a dataset for each run, write the following code in ***After simulation run:*** field:

```
excelFile.writeDataSet(root.dataset, 1, 1, column*2 + 1);
column++;
```

A dataset takes two columns, this is why you need to multiply column by 2 in the code to avoid overwriting of previous data.

On the other hand, if you want to export a single value, such as mean duration, use the following code:

```
excelFile.setCellValue(root.mean, 1, 1, row + 1);
row++;
```

The row and column method is not set in stone, you can add the data vertically, horizontally or any other way, just get familiar with how Excel functions work (i.e. `writeDataSet` and `setCellValue` and similar).

Also in the example above `mean` is assumed to be a variable. You can replace it with any other code that returns a single value such as `statistics.mean()`.

Comment: Does this answer imply that I have a dataset already made because I receive the error that dataset cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I was mostly answering the second part of the question where you mentioned exporting a data set. I am not familiar with exporting statistics_log data.

Comment: Ah understood. So a dataset in main is needed for this to work?

Comment: Well it depends what you're trying to achieve. My understanding is you are running the same simulation multiple times to get results for different parameters or for the same parameters but with a different seed. To make sense of these results, you need to store them somewhere so that you can look at them. These results may be a single number (e.g. duration of simulation, total cost, etc.) or datasets (e.g. weekly costs, daily visitors, etc.). The code I sent you will store data set results. Feel free to tell me what data you want to store so I can better help.

Comment: I am running the same simulation multiple times to get results for different parameters, yes! The data I would like to collect the means of various ```timeMeasureStart``` / ```timeMeasureEnd``` blocks that time different segments of my model. Ideally to be compared to those same means of a simulation with changed parameters.

Comment: I updated the answer to be more generic for your case. Let me know if it doesn't help but it should give you a good idea on how to proceed.

Comment: When you mentioned 'If you want to export a dataset', does that mean I will need a dataset in main taking in data from a particular timeMeasureEnd block?

Comment: No, I just meant a dataset element. If you're interested in the data of a timeMeasureEnd  block, the same concept applies, but use the second function I gave in my answer. `excelFile.setCellValue(root.timeMeasureEnd.distribution.mean(), 1, 1, row + 1);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242606/discussion-between-nicka-and-emile-zankoul).